# Mirror reflection of the picture Java

Tags: java, image

Hi so i have to make mirror reflection of my drawn picture. There must be 2 pictures. One normal and the second right below as mirror reflection. I don't know how to draw second picture and flip it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String path ="C:/Users/Desktop/Snow.ppm";
    FileReader fReader = new FileReader(path);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fReader);
    String p3=inFile.nextLine();
    String program=inFile.nextLine();
    int rows=inFile.nextInt();
    int cols=inFile.nextInt();
    int maxValue=inFile.nextInt();
    int[][] red = new int [rows][cols];
    int[][] green = new int [rows][cols];
    int[][] blue = new int [rows][cols];
    for (int c = 0; c<cols;c++){
        for(int r =0; r<rows; r++){
            red[r][c]=inFile.nextInt();
            green[r][c]=inFile.nextInt();
            blue[r][c]=inFile.nextInt();
        }
    }

    inFile.close();

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(rows, cols, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    for (int c = 0; c<cols;c++){
        for(int r =0; r<rows; r++){
            int rgb = red[r][c];
            rgb=(rgb<<8)+green[r][c];
            rgb=(rgb<<8)+blue[r][c];
            img.setRGB(r, c, rgb);
        }
    }

    JLabel jLabel=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
    JPanel jPanel=new JPanel();
    jPanel.add(jLabel);

    JFrame r = new JFrame();
    r.setSize(rows+100, cols+100);
    r.add(jPanel);  
    r.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You want to deal with horizontally (or perhaps vertically) flipping an image. We can help you with that, but we are (or at least I am) not interested in any GUI code.

Comment: You can just reverse the traversal direction of one dimension to flip the image accordingly.